# How to accelerate matlab code?

Tags: performance, matlab, neural-network

I'm using matlab to implement a multilayer neural network. In the code I represent

the value of each node AS **netValue{k}**

the weight between layer k and k + 1 AS **weight{k}**

etc.

Since these data is three-dimensional, I have to use cell to hold a 2-D matrix to enable matrix multiply.

So it becomes really really slow to train the model, which I expect to have resulted from the usage of cell.

Can anyone tell me how to accelerate this code? Thanks

```
clc; 
close all;
clear all;

input = [-2 : 0.4 : 2;-2:0.4:2]; 
ican = 4;

depth = 4;  % total layer - 1, by convension
[featureNum , sampleNum] = size(input); 
levelNum(1) = featureNum;  
levelNum(2) = 5;
levelNum(3) = 5;
levelNum(4) = 5;
levelNum(5) = 2;


weight = cell(0);
for k = 1 : depth
    weight{k} = rand(levelNum(k+1), levelNum(k)) - 2 * rand(levelNum(k+1) , levelNum(k));
    threshold{k} = rand(levelNum(k+1) , 1) - 2 * rand(levelNum(k+1) , 1);
end

runCount = 0;
sumMSE = 1; % init MSE 
minError = 1e-5;

afa = 0.1; % step of "gradient ascendence"

% training loop
while(runCount < 100000 & sumMSE > minError)  
    sumMSE = 0; % sum of MSE
    for i = 1 : sampleNum % sample loop
        netValue{1} = input(:,i);

        for k = 2 : depth
            netValue{k} = weight{k-1} * netValue{k-1} + threshold{k-1}; %calculate each layer 
            netValue{k} = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-netValue{k})); %apply logistic function 
        end
        netValue{depth+1} = weight{depth} * netValue{depth} + threshold{depth}; %output layer


        e = 1 + sin((pi / 4) * ican * netValue{1}) - netValue{depth + 1}; %calc error
        assistS{depth} = diag(ones(size(netValue{depth+1})));
        s{depth} = -2 * assistS{depth} * e;
        for k = depth - 1 : -1 : 1
            assistS{k} = diag((1-netValue{k+1}).*netValue{k+1});
            s{k} = assistS{k} * weight{k+1}' * s{k+1};  
        end

        for k = 1 : depth
            weight{k} = weight{k} - afa * s{k} * netValue{k}';
            threshold{k} = threshold{k} - afa * s{k};
        end

        sumMSE = sumMSE + e' * e;  
    end  
    sumMSE = sqrt(sumMSE) / sampleNum;  
    runCount = runCount + 1;  
end  

x = [-2 : 0.1 : 2;-2:0.1:2];  
y = zeros(size(x));  
z = 1 + sin((pi / 4) * ican .* x);  
% test
for i = 1 : length(x)  
    netValue{1} = x(:,i);
    for k = 2 : depth
        netValue{k} = weight{k-1} * netValue{k-1} + threshold{k-1};
        netValue{k} = 1 ./ ( 1 + exp(-netValue{k}));
    end
    y(:, i) = weight{depth} * netValue{depth} + threshold{depth};
end  

plot(x(1,:) , y(1,:) , 'r');  
hold on;  

plot(x(1,:) , z(1,:) , 'g');  

hold off;
```

Comment: You need to [preallocate](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/techniques-for-improving-performance.html) your cell arrays!

Comment: Thx. I think that's an important point. And I should follow other advice by the matlab IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used the `profiler` to find out what functions are actually slowing down your code? It shows what lines take the most time to execute.

Comment: Please be more specific. And is it like the performance utilities in MS Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: `doc profile` would be a good start. Quick start:

`profile on;`
`my_code_here;`
`profile viewer;`

Comment: I have just used it and that's exactly what I want! Thanks a lot.